# Convert raw bytes to a type in .NET

Tags: .net, types, arcgis, esri

I have the raw bytes of a COM object (ESRI IPOINT) in a SQL DB.  I want to somehow force the casting of it to an IPOINT.  I tried IPoint p = object as IPOINT which failed.  Is there some hacky way to force raw bytes into an object for which there isn't a converter written?

Comment: I'll post this as an answer if it works, but does this help? http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3897

Comment: How did the raw bytes get into the DB originally?

Comment: @iterationx where did the binary data in the database come from? If you know how the object was serialized in the first place then there is probably a paired approach for deserialization. If the object was serialized into binary in the COM (i.e. non-.NET) world then trying to deserialize it in the .NET world is probably going to be made much more difficult.

Comment: @Daniel Renshaw  Well first it was stored in an ESRI shapefile which was created by ArcGIS by another company and sent to me, then it was converted to an .mdb SQL file by a call to some arcane ESRI libraries.

Comment: @keyboardP Thanks but that doesn't help

Comment: @iterationx then I guess your best bet is to find some documentation for those arcane libraries and try to find information on how to extract the embedded objects.

Comment: @keyboardP, `BinaryFormatter` is something completely different. It serializes lots of metadata with the actual objects and expects them at deserialization too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the appropriate way is to do this is to use a QueryFilter,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to access a GeoDatabase file.

Here's some info on making a connection: [Connect to a Personal Geodatabase](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/Samples/Geodatabase/Accessing_Data/Connect_to_a_personal_geodatabase.htm) and [How to connect to a geodatabase](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/c778d2bb-eb36-4793-9c89-20795811c5eb.htm)